# Funny character in Javascript but not in HTML

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I am using Flask, and when rendering template, the variable in HTML and JavaScript is different.

**In HTML, I have the below code.**

```
{{display}}
```

Output:

{"financial_year": ["2019-12-30", "2018-12-30"], "revenue": [14500, 13000]}

**In JavaScript, I have the below code.**

```
var display = '{{display}}';
alert(display);
```

Output:
[image]

I am trying to parse {{display}} using JSON.parse, the below error comes up:

> VM318:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 1
> at JSON.parse ()
> at (index):547

Does anyone has a solution to allow me to parse the json object?

Comment: You're using a templating engine designed to create HTML to create JavaScript code. Jinja (the templating engine Flask uses) does thorough HTML escaping to (help) prevent XSS vulnerabilities. You'll need to either generate the code another way, or find whatever feature it is that lets you output raw text rather than HTML-encoded text. (I couldn't find it in a couple of minutes of searching -- I don't use Flask, Jinja, or indeed, Python), so posting a comment rather than answer. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks Crowder! They have identified a similar question and I got the solution I wanted. Thanks for helping me to understand the concept of escape data!

Comment: My pleasure! Happy coding! :-)